# Append to Zipfile Self-Made Function

Tags: python

The closest question to mine is this one: 
Python 2.6 - Add a file to zipfile without folders 
But it's not exactly what I'm looking for.

I' m trying to define a pretty simple function, and after debugging I still can't catch why, in the for loop, the Disclaimer - Final.txt file is only being appended to one zip file, and not both?

This function does a few things: it finds the zipfile--> then removes the zipfile --> then calls another function 'zipshapes' which zips a new file--> then it appends the txt file.

```
import zipfile, os
from ZipFiles import zipshapes 

path = r'\\gisfile\GISstaff\Jared\Python Scripts\Disclaimer - Final.txt'
zips = [r'\\gisfile\GISstaff\Jared\Python Scripts\Test\WillCounty_AddressPoint.zip',
        r'\\gisfile\GISstaff\Jared\Python Scripts\Test\WillCounty_Street.zip'] # list of zip folders

def append2zip():
  for zip in zips: # loop through zipfolders
    if os.path.exists(zip):
      os.remove(zip)
      print('removed: {}'.format(zip))
      zipshapes()
      zf = zipfile.ZipFile(zip,mode='a')
      zf.write(path,os.path.basename(path))
      print('disclaimer appended: {}'.format(zip))
      return 'append2zip'

append2zip() # call function above
```

Comment: Your function hits a `return` statement at the end of its first pass through the `for` loop, so it never gets to the second pass.

Comment: @glibdud Thank you. That did it. 

I commented out the 'return' line and ran it. It seems as though it loops through three times based on the 'zipshapes' function print statements. They're repeated three times in the interactive window. Any idea why?